# What is the best practice for porting #defines from .h file to a C# application?

Tags: c#, c++, compiler-directives

I am converting an application from C++ to C#. The C++ application has a defines file .h with over 500 #define directives. I would like to represent this data in a Definition.cs file. **What is the best way to do this?**

An example of the defines:

```
//Digital ouputs
#define FLAGLEDCOOL             "BIT12032"
#define FLAGLEDLASERINTLK       "BIT12036"
#define FLAGLEDLASERSTANBDY     "BIT12038"
...

//Digital inputs
#define FLAGSTATUSINTLKRELAY    "BIT11535"
#define FLAGSTATUSEMERGRELAY    "BIT11533"
#define FLAGSTATUSKVMRELAY      "BIT11531"
...
```

The #defines are grouped so this make me think of using properties, such as:

```
public class DigitalOuputs
{
    public static string FLAGLEDCOOL { get; }
    public static string FLAGLEDLASERINTLK { get; }
    public static string FLAGLEDLASERSTANBDY { get; }
    ...
}

public class DigitalInputs
{
    public static string FLAGSTATUSINTLKRELAY { get; }
    public static string FLAGSTATUSEMERGRELAY { get; }
    public static string FLAGSTATUSKVMRELAY { get; }
    ...
}
```

Although I would have to set the default value in a constructor, which im trying to avoid, and they should be read-only.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just declare them as consts - a [const is implicitly a static](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2004/03/12/why-can-t-i-use-code-static-code-and-code-const-code-together.aspx) as well:

```
public class DigitalOuputs
{
  public const string FLAGLEDCOOL ="BIT12032"
  ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Oded for the quick response. Would it be better to use an `enum`?

Comment: @Ryan - I don't see how, since enums can't be strings.

Comment: @Ryan - XML will not give you the same ease of access (you need to read it and parse it first). If that's not a problem (you can wrap this in a class), you can, but I think it would just add complexity with very little benefit.